# Reward players for dumb actions regarding NPC interactions or not?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, group-dynamics

To setup the scene.
In a political intrigue game (with fighting). The game was advertised where both elements can be of use but one or the other won't always net all the solutions when I pitched it to the group.

There are several Named NPC characters that have met and talked with the players.
The players have from the start been seeking information from these NPCs that is 100% the unvarnished truth.

Now because this is an intrigue game those NPCs are looking out for their own interests so they setup their opponents to fail or they don't give all the details to the players.

This having become obvious has led the players to not want to deal with those NPCs anymore and even not wanting to deal with NPCs that are on their side but don't have the answers they need (they ask a guy who wasn't in the city at the time what happened in a room in a building etc...).

This has led to them basically tossing aside (literally in the case of an actual talking head) helpful people. I set it up so they took the head back but are now still insistent on crushing it at every turn when it isn't able to give them an answer to something it doesn't know.

Now I don't find that this is a problem. But two of the players have grown frustrated that they aren't getting all the information (also the two that are more likely to smash everyone) and have voiced their complaints as such.
This makes me a bit frustrated as it's a self-fulfilling prophecy in my mind.
**Should I be more lenient or should I continue as is and have them fail?**

**One note:** they are not even digging around behind the backs of people they know are lying to them for information. It's talk to them head on or nothing.
I would like to encourage more than this but have been told, by the previously mentioned, that it's not worth it since "all information is unreliable."

Comment: Just to be clear, is it the *characters* who are frustrated, or the *players*? If the latter, you should probably clarify with them if they know that you're doing intrigue.

Comment: It is the latter and they were informed of it constantly before the game started and they agreed to it.

Comment: @jgn That sounds very close to the start of an answer, and comments are not for answering the question, even if it is closed. (Maybe especially not then.)